# View MS-Office Documents in ASP.NET site (Dynamically)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office

Goal: Displaying MS-Office documents in my website.

I have been looking at so many "solutions" on the web and could not find one that suits my needs, they are either not good or cost way too much (GroupDocs etc).

The existing answers on SO are just depressing...

I need to show my users documents on the page but not allow them to download them.

The only thing that seemed good and affordable was the [Office Web Viewer](http://officewebviewer.com), as recommended on the Office Blog Page [Office Blog - Office Web Viewer](http://blogs.office.com/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/), but I guess they took down the app or it's just not working.

I was just wondering whether anyone heard of a solution for that?

Comment: @Smeegs, I have a lot of documents being uploaded daily to the site. I can build a converter for that but I rather not

Comment: Yeah, I saw "dynamically" and that answered my question.

Comment: Does this help http://forums.asp.net/t/1937231.aspx?Office+and+pdf+document+viewer+

Comment: Thank you @JamesBlackbjBlackburn but this I cannot afford a tool for 1800+ USD

Comment: Ah didnt realize it was a pay for one sorry!

Comment: Are you sure that service you linked is unavailable? the samples from the blog still work, even if the main link isn't. I notice that it gives a download option though when following the sample links. I had a similar scenario, and ended up using Office InterOp (actually [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) ) to save documents to PDF when uploaded, so there was a browser-viewable copy available

Comment: @JamesS, I am not sure where you saw the download link, but if you could elaborate a little more "I would be so happy".
In addition, the NetOffice seems interesting, is it for viewing the files?

Comment: Heres one of the examples [link](http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http%3A%2F%2Flearn.bankofamerica.com%2Fcontent%2Fexcel%2FWedding_Budget_Planner_Spreadsheet.xlsx) You can see a link at the top of the document to download it. I assume just by changing the URL it would also work with other documents you had online. As far as NetOffice goes its an alternative to the Office Primary Interop Assemblies. It allows you to automate an installed version of Microsoft office on the same machine, so you can manipulate office documents (eg save as PDF). The Office UI can remain hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone still  interested, you can use Doconut viewer or even pay a little more and use DevExpress etc.